# Timer in PHP on registration

Tags: php

I want to make little timer on my registration, per user. So basically I want to make it when someone makes the account, they are put on timer for lets say 5 minutes before registering again (same user).

I've tried the below, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    exit('user already exists');
} else {
    $expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',+30);
if($now>$expire) {
    create new acc
} else {
   exit('You need to wait.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "+ 5 min to expire" docs: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

```
  $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        exit('user already exists');
    } else {
        $expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', "+ 5 minutes");
    if($now>$expire) {
        create new acc
   } else {
       exit('You need to wait.');
   }
```

You can basically use this code it will work

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working, i can keep on making the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet will not work. Both variables, `$now` and `$expire`, are defined on the same flow.

On time of evaluation, the expression `$now>$expire` is never true.

You need store the state for the lock. One way to achieve this is a cookie that carries the date of last registration attempt.

PseudoCode

```
if isRegistered(user): exit("Already signed up")
else if notSet(cookie['lastAttemptAt']) : proceedWithSignUp()
else if cookie['lastAttemptAt'].plus(5, Minutes) < now() : proceedWithSignUp()
else : exit("You need to wait")
```

in this case the function `proceedWithSignUp` needs to take care as well to set the cookie value of `lastAttemptAt`

Be aware, that this can be easily by passed, by either not accepting cookies at all or clearing the cookies.